# Testing an OSX app on the store but not making it public

Tags: macos, app-store

I would like to distribute my OSX app on the store and test the whole process (using a fresh mac to download and run my app from the store), before I make it live.

Is there any way I can have it be on the store but unlisted? Or another way I can test that is guaranteed to work exactly as it would if you were to download it from the store?

Thanks

Comment: Downloading from the store is not different than testing it through xcode... Remember that your app is reviewed before being published. What are you afraid of?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I would like to ensure that the Apple store is clever enough to create patch files instead of re downloading the whole new version of the app. My app is ~200mb and a lot of my customers are in rural areas without great internet, so if Apple is unable to create a patch file then I will go back to my custom patcher.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able use a promo code to download your app from the Mac App store, even if the app is released but disabled from distribution in your country (or in all countries, or maybe all except one tiny one where no one downloads apps).